# Como digo "zoom" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Costumo traduzir o termo *zoom* como *aproximar*. No entanto, não tenho certeza sobre esta tradução, pois mesmo usando ferramentas de edição de imagens em português, o termo estrangeiro é adotado.

Se utilizo o [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.br/?source=osdd#auto/en/aproximar) e digito "aproximar", o termo não é traduzido para "zoom". No entanto, utilizando o mesmo [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.br/?source=osdd#en/pt/zoom) e digitando "zoom", algumas coisas curiosas acontecem. A primeira delas é que a ferramenta detecta automaticamente o idioma português. Além disso, a palavra é traduzida do inglês para o português automaticamente para "zoom" também, mas se clico na palavra traduzida, para ler o rol de traduções alternativas, aparecem tanto "Aproximar" quanto "Afastar imagem".

Afinal, como traduzo a palavra *zoom*?

Comment: *Zoom* pode ser *zoom in* ou *zoom out*, e ainda a lente propriamente dita [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zoom), daí talvez o *aproximar* e *afastar* É claro que isto não ajuda muito na tradução. O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/zoom) reconhece o uso de *zoom* em português.

Comment: Eu traduziria como "zoom", usa-se muito por aqui "faz ai um zoom" no sentido de aproximar a imagem.

Comment: ampliar a imagem, dar uma "aumentada" na imagem, aplicar o zoom, esticar a imagem (essa opção pode expressar deformação da imagem)

Comment: Os termos que já vi cinegrafistas usarem são "abrir" e "fechar" para zoom out e zoom out respectivamente. Ex: "Fecha no repórter, depois abre enquadrando a rua..."

Comment: Algumas definições se chocam pois existe zoom de uma câmera que traz para perto ou afasta a imagem, e o zoom que programas de computador aplicam em imagens que aumentam ou diminuem a imagem visualizada na tela.

Comment: Sim, no em cinema e vídeo, abrir ou fechar por causa da distância focal...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Talvez você já conheça a ferramenta web [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com.br), mas caso não conheça, é uma ótima ferramenta que faz ás vezes do Google Translate, porém busca pela tradução de forma contextual, ou seja, baseado em exemplos de uso na web.

Utilizo-a bastante quando preciso fazer alguma tradução.

Ao buscar a [tradução de zoom](http://www.linguee.com.br/portugues-ingles/search?source=ingles&query=zoom) nessa ferramenta, é possível notar que a palavra *zoom* é largamente utilizada em textos em português (ao menos ptBR) e, quando é traduzida, a expressão utilizada é *aumentar*.

Nota-se ainda que a expressão *diminuir* (conforme sugerido pelo Google Translate) praticamente não é utilizada como tradução de zoom (apenas 3 casos de uso).

Tendo isso em vista, eu traduziria sempre como *zoom* mesmo, com exceção de casos bastante específicos onde aumentar ou diminuir soasse claramente mais apropriado. Tenho certeza que seu texto será compreendido se utilizar zoom.

Answer (score 6):

No dicionário Houaiss, versão monousuário 3.0 -  Junho de 2009, aparece ***zum*** com essa definição:

[image]

Ou seja, o termo inglês *zoom* já foi aportuguesado, com a mesma pronúncia, porém com grafia *zum*.

Comment: É uma grafia curiosa. Eu esperaria *zume*, para corresponder melhor à pronúncia. Assim, só *zum*, eu tenderia a pronunciar /zũ/, como em *zunzum*. (A foto do Houaiss tem letras tão miudinhas, incluí logo a palavra na frase inicial.)

Comment: @Jacinto _"A foto do Houaiss tem letras tão miudinhas"_ - Seria o caso de um zum, então?

Comment: @Jacinto tens de ver a pronuncia em pt-BR que se aproxima mais de zum.

Comment: @Bacco, é, a foto precisava de um zumin :)

Comment: @Jorge, tás a dizer que os brasileiros, mesmo se for *zoom*, pronunciam *zũ*, rimando com *um, atum, catrapum*?

Comment: @Jacinto ao que parece pronunciam como no inglês.

Comment: @Jorge, mas em inglês o *m* é mesmo pronunciado, enquanto nas palavra portugueses o *-m* final não é pronunciado como *m*; nasaliza a vogal anterior (como *um, atum*)

Comment: Acho que se diz: zume acrecentando uma sílaba.